# Jquery Dialog box with gmaps.js

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-ui, gmaps.js

i'm facing a problem to show google map in a dialog box, the map shows in the dialog box like below

[image]

i'm using [gmaps.js](https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/) library to show google map and [jquery ui](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/) for the dialog box

Here is my code snippet

```
<?php if ( ! empty( $latitude ) && ! empty( $longtitude ) ): ?>

    <li class="click-n-pick-span">
       <a href="#" id="opener-<?php echo $branch->ID ?>">
          <?php _e( 'Our location on map', \Click_And_Pick\Click_And_Pick::TEXTDOMAIN ) ?>
                            </a>
    </li>

    <div class="modal-header">
        <div class="dialog" id="map-<?php echo $branch->ID ?>-content"
                                 style="width:500px !important; height:500px !important"></div>
        </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and the js like the following :

```
<?php if ( ! empty( $latitude ) && ! empty( $longtitude ) ): ?>

    // google map
    var map = new GMaps({
    div: '#map-<?php echo $branch->ID ?>-content',
    lat: <?php echo $latitude ?>,
    lng: <?php echo $longtitude ?>
    });

    map.addMarker({
        lat: <?php echo $latitude ?>,
        lng: <?php echo $longtitude ?>
    });

    $("#map-<?php echo $branch->ID ?>-content").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        zoom: 12,
        width: 'auto'
    });

    $("#opener-<?php echo $branch->ID ?>").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        map.refresh();
        $("#map-<?php echo $branch->ID ?>-content").dialog("open");
    });


    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Run this on it once your html elements height and width are set.

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')
```

Taken from this page..  [Gmaps API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map)
Under events, it says this ...

> Developers should trigger this event on the map when the div changes
>   size: google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize') .

Or maybe try this..

[Size()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Size)

This page seems pretty helpful...

[GMAPS API V3 Github.io](http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples.html)

Have you tried setting height and width of the map object when you create it ?

```
    // google map
    var map = new GMaps({
        div: '#map-<?php echo $branch->ID ?>-content',
        lat: <?php echo $latitude ?>,
        lng: <?php echo $longtitude ?>,
        width: 500,
        height: 500
    });
```

Or set inline style to set width on your modal header div ?

```
<div style="width: 500px;" class="modal-header">
```